# mean stack console not working in terminal

Tags: javascript, mean-stack

I have a problem with the `console.log(jwt_payload)` it won't print in the terminal I have other logs and they will print to the terminal but for some reason this won't print for me. I have tried other soloutions out there but no such luck.

```
module.exports = function(passport){
let opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("JWT");
opts.secretOrKey = Config.secret;

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    console.log(jwt_payload);
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err, false);
        }

        if(user){
            return done(null, user);
        }else{
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));
```

}

Comment: try  console.log(typeof jwt_payload);

Comment: Akash that did not work I have tried everything so frustrating ha

Comment: I think this whole block is not being executed
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    console.log(jwt_payload);
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err, false);
        }

        if(user){
            return done(null, user);
        }else{
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));
}